# Conditional probability brain teaser on square (0-1)-matrices

Tags: probability, probability-theory

This problem seems to me a brain teaser, in the form of a probability puzzle. I would be really grateful if someone could help me to solve this simple conditional probability problem.
We have a $n \times n$ $(0,1)$-matrix $M$. Let $R$ be the set of rows and let $C$ be the set of columns. Finally, we indicate the $i$-th row and column with $R_i$ and $C_i$ respectively, and the set $\{1, 2, ..., n\}$ with $[n]$.

We have the following information:

(1) Given any $i \in [n]$ and $y \in \{0,1\}$, we know the number $f_{y}(R_i)$ of indices $k \in [n]$ such that $M_{i, k}=y$. Analogously, we also know the number $f_{y}(C_i)$ of indices $k \in [n]$ such that $M_{k, i}=y$.

(2) Given any pair of integers $(i,j) \in [n] \times [n]$ and any value $y \in \{0,1\}$, we know the number $f_{y, 1}(R_i, R_j)$ of vector component indices $k$ such that $M_{j,k}=1$ when $M_{i,k}=y$.

---

We select at the same time three integers $i$, $j$ and $k$ uniformly at random in $[n]$. We then read the value of $M_{i, k}$ and observe it is equal to a certain value $y$ (where therefore $y \in \{0,1\}$).

QUESTION: How can we calculate the probability that $M_{j,k}=1$?

Using the second part of information (1) solely, I guess one would answer $f_{1}(C_k)/n$. On the other hand, using all information except the second part of (1), I guess one would answer $f_{y, 1}(R_i, R_j)/f_{y}(R_i)$ (please observe $f_{y}(R_i)$ cannot be null). I do not know how to combine all the information.

Thank you very much for your help!
Cheers,
T.